# Page keeps on loading in Chrome Driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I m working on a web application automation and I have this issue with Chrome driver. The page keeps on loading and it does not move to the next action.

For eg: The successful login scenario.

The application is launched and the username passwords are keyed in Successfully and the home page is loaded.
The home page keeps on loading that it does not move to the next button click (eg. log out)
If I manually stop the browser refreshing, it performs the next click but then again the browser keeps on loading.

I have already included

```
 this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I have tried sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE) too. Nothing seem to work

Comment: Does this happen only through code? What version of browser, chromedriver and selenium are you using?

Comment: @AnishPillai Yes, it only happens in the webdriver , chrome browser version : 57,  Selenium 3.3.1

Comment: I also tried upgrading the browser to the latest 58, still no luck

Comment: I have encountered the same issue when running ChromeDriver from the command line. I have raised an issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1798

Comment: @Underscore I ve made a  comment on that issue as well, if you come across any solution please do share it ...

Comment: @ManoKugan, Underscore:  Are you guys got any solution to resolve it? If so, please share it.

Comment: Hi @ManoKugan ! I have the same issues. Have you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @Fabi and Manigandan not yet,